# Spring boot Kafka - Sending a message to DLT and Retry topic does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Spring boot Kafka - When I send a message to DLT and Retry topic from my application, I am able to send it.

When an exception happens and framework tries to send the message it never works. No errors as well. The message stays in original topic and kept getting consumed and throws errors and repeat itself.

If the application is failing to publish why its not logging anything. This happens for bith blocking and non blocking retries.

`@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

```
private final KafkaPropertiesConfig kafkaPropertiesConfig;
private final IdpsPropertiesConfig idpsPropertiesConfig;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConfig.class);

public KafkaConfig(KafkaPropertiesConfig kafkaPropertiesConfig, IdpsPropertiesConfig idpsPropertiesConfig) {
    this.kafkaPropertiesConfig = kafkaPropertiesConfig;
    this.idpsPropertiesConfig = idpsPropertiesConfig;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(kafkaPropertiesConfig.getConcurrency());
    factory.setAutoStartup(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(kafkaPropertiesConfig.getIdleEventInterval());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);

    setListenerErrorHandler(factory);

    return factory;
}

private void setListenerErrorHandler(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>> factory) {
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(
            new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplateDLT(),
                    (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition(cr.topic() + "-dlt", cr.partition())),
            new FixedBackOff(kafkaPropertiesConfig.getBlockingBackoffTimeInMillis(), kafkaPropertiesConfig.getBlockingNumRetries())));
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>> consumerFactory() {
    Properties idpsProps = getIdpsProperties();
    Properties kafkaProps = getKafkaProperties();

    com.intuit.eventbus.Configuration<Decrypter<EncryptedData, byte[]>> decryptConf = new IDPSDecrypter.Config(idpsProps);

    DeserializingMessageExtractor<String, MetadataV3> extractor = new DeserializingMessageExtractorImpl.Config<>(new DefaultValidator.Config<>(),
            ProvisioningMethods.permissiveExtractor(decryptConf), com.intuit.eventbus.serialization.StringDeserializer::new).instantiate();

    Deserializer<String> messageDeserializer = new Deserializer<>(extractor);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>>(new HashMap(kafkaProps), new StringDeserializer(), messageDeserializer);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Properties idpsProps = getIdpsProperties();
    Properties kafkaProps = getKafkaProperties();

    com.intuit.eventbus.Configuration<SerializingMessageFormater<String, MetadataV3>> formatterConf = new SerializingMessageFormaterImpl.Config<>(
            new DefaultValidator.Config<>(), new FormaterV3.Config(new IDPSEncrypter.Config(kafkaPropertiesConfig.getEnvironment(), idpsProps)),
            com.intuit.eventbus.serialization.StringSerializer::new);

    Serializer<String> messageSerializer = new Serializer<>(formatterConf.instantiate());
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String>(new HashMap(kafkaProps), new StringSerializer(), messageSerializer);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>> producerFactoryDLT() {
    Properties idpsProps = getIdpsProperties();
    Properties kafkaProps = getKafkaProperties();

    com.intuit.eventbus.Configuration<SerializingMessageFormater<Result<FormatException, String>, MetadataV3>> formatterConf = new SerializingMessageFormaterImpl.Config<>(
            new DefaultValidator.Config<>(), new FormaterV3.Config(new IDPSEncrypter.Config(kafkaPropertiesConfig.getEnvironment(), idpsProps)),
            ResultSerializer::new);

    Serializer<Result<FormatException, String>> messageSerializer = new Serializer<>(formatterConf.instantiate());
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Result<FormatException, String>>(new HashMap(kafkaProps), new StringSerializer(), messageSerializer);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Result<FormatException, String>> kafkaTemplateDLT() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactoryDLT());
}

private Properties getIdpsProperties() {
    Properties result = new Properties();
    result.putAll(idpsPropertiesConfig.getIdpsProperties().entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> (e.getValue() != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(e.getValue().toString()))).map(this::transformIdpsProperty)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(), Map.Entry::getValue)));
    return result;
}

private Properties getKafkaProperties() {
    Properties result = new Properties();
    result.putAll(kafkaPropertiesConfig.getKafkaProperties().entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> (e.getValue() != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(e.getValue().toString()))).map(this::transformKafkaProperty)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(), Map.Entry::getValue)));
    return result;
}

/**
 * Kafka only understands files can't load resources from classpath
 *
 */
private Map.Entry<Object, Object> transformIdpsProperty(Map.Entry<Object, Object> property) {

    if ("api_secret_key".equals(property.getKey()) && (property.getValue() != null)) {
        property.setValue(ResourceUtils.resourceToTempFile(property.getValue().toString()));
    }
    return property;
}

private Map.Entry<Object, Object> transformKafkaProperty(Map.Entry<Object, Object> property) {

    if ("ssl.truststore.location".equals(property.getKey())) {
        property.setValue(ResourceUtils.resourceToTempFile(property.getValue().toString()));
    }
    return property;
}

public static class ResultSerializer implements com.intuit.eventbus.Serializer<Result<FormatException, String>>, Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8057420295710787523L;

    @Override
    public byte[] apply(Result<FormatException, String> t, SchemaContext<Result<FormatException, String>> schemaContext) {
        byte[] result;

        if (t.isSuccess()) {
            result = t.get().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            logger.info(String.format("Success serialize result to string topicName: %s: result: %s", schemaContext.getTopicName(), new String(result)));
        } else {
            result = t.getFailure().getMessage().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            logger.info(String.format("Failure serialize result to string topicName: %s: result: %s", schemaContext.getTopicName(), new String(result)));
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

}`